# Termux NodeJS - npm install fails, cannot create symbolic link. Workaround

Tags: node.js, npm-install, symlink, termux

Termux will not allow you to create symbolic links in /storage/emulated/0.  This is due to a design limitation with its file system. Thus, some npm installs will fail with the following error:

```
    npm install js-yaml

    npm ERR! code EPERM                           
    npm ERR! syscall symlink                      
    npm ERR! path ../esprima/bin/esparse.js
```

Workaround #1:

Perform the npm install globally:

```
    npm install --global js-yaml
```

If your program won't run because it can't find the package:

```
    var yaml = require('js-yaml');

    Error: Cannot find module 'js-yaml'
```

Workaround #2:

Hard-code the full path in your program as such:

```
    var yaml = require('/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml.js');
```

Please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution.

#### INSTALL GLOBAL NPM PACKAGES

`npm config set unsafe-perm true`

#### CLEAN CACHE

`npm cache clean`

#### BYPASS SYMLINK ISSUES

`npm install --no-bin-links`

Comment: Great! I am so glad that it works for you. If you don't mind, I believe that ticking it as a correct answer will help other developers who would be in same situation.